# Сообщение, зашифрованное в картинке. Реализация. Велосипед с "тайнописью"

Tags: изображения, gd, php

Текст разбивается на куски по 2 бита: `ord`, потом 4 раза

```
$mpieces[] = ($letter_ord >> 2) & 3;
```

Потом в каждый цвет в последние два бита забивается кусок буквы:

```
$color[$n] = ($color[$n] >> 2)<<2 + array_shift($mpieces);
```

В итоге, картинка из 16М цветов превращается в 262к с легким шумом. При беглом осмотре незаметно.
Но мне кажется, сочетание `imagecolorat + imagesetpixel` не самое рациональное.
Можно ли как то осуществить это же быстрее?

**UPDATE:**

Если сделать array_reverse, а вместо array_shift юзать array_pop, можно получить колоссальный выйгрыш в скорости. Настолько большой, что вопрос можно считать закрытым.

**UPDATE2:**

И еще момент: побитовый сдвиг, внезапно, имеет более низкий приоритет, чем сложение. Поэтомму окончательно строчка выглядит так:

```
$color[$n] = (($color[$n] >> 2) << 2) + array_pop($mpieces);
```

Comment: [В Великобритании вас бы полюбили](http://habrahabr.ru/post/147769/) :)

Насколько я знаю, у GD нет чего-то типа scanLine().

Кстати, интересно: как будете бороться с JPEG, не поделитесь?

Comment: Про реалтайм пока не скажу, но я бы кэшировал картинки в raw формат - что-то типа `[long width][long height][rgb x width * height]` и работал в дальнейшем с этим файлом. 

Для случая "одна картинка, много сообщений" вполне покатит. 

Для случая "наоборот" - пока рискнул бы только предложить сделать CGI-скрипт на сях, например, и ему скармливать картинку.

Comment: @Bars,

  >если они не смогут предъявить ключ к своим зашифрованным данным.  

Ключ тут есть. Причем элементарный.
С JPEG можно бороться избыточностью, если возникнет такая необходимость. Но пока такой необходимости нет, цели другие.

@Sh4dow, в общем, ответ. Особенно с массивом идея понравилась. По крайней мере, так не придется заново вытягивать пиксели.
Кстати, внезапно pop работает много быстрее шифта О_о